# Observers Not Removed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory, memory-management

I'm adding buttons to a UITableViewHeader, but getting console messages that observers were not removed before deallocation:

> An instance 0x4b4750 of class UIButton was deallocated while key value
>   observers were still registered with it

That's understandable, so I'm trying to remove them but unsure of the best way to go about this. The only thing which springs to mind is to add them all to an array, then in dealloc, loop through them all and remove the class which created them as an observer. I'm not entirely sure which parameters to pass into `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver` though. There are are three different buttons in each header view, each firing a different callback. Does this mean I'd need three arrays, on for each type of action called, then use `removeTarget`?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Important The notification center does not retain its observers,
>   therefore, you must ensure that you unregister observers (using
>   removeObserver: or removeObserver:name:object:) before they are
>   deallocated. (If you don't, you will generate a runtime error if the
>   center sends a message to a freed object.)

If you have subclassed the buttons, then you could post a message to all observers that the observable UIButton is about to go kaput.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"UIButton_dealloc" object:self];
```

Or, in the class that allocates the buttons, once the buttons will be removed you can:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"UIButton_dealloc" object:theButton];
```

And the observer objects, in both cases, will do this:

```
// The special event
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(doSomething:) name:@"UIButton_event" object:theButton];
// The dealloc
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(stopObserving:) name:@"UIButton_dealloc" object:theButton];
....
-(void) stopObserving:(NSNotification*)notif {
    if ([name isEqualToString:@"UIButton_dealloc"]) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"UIButton_event" object:object]; 
    }
}
```

However, this is a somewhat convoluted example in the case of a UIButton, but can be useful for other cases.

Comment: I'm not sure how this would map to the control events I'm currently using. To add the observer, I'm currently using `addTarget`, so if I `addTarget` would I not need to also `removeTarget`? Either way, is an array to keep track the best approach?

Comment: I think it would, see http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/06/five-approaches-to-listening-observing.html for observer info

Comment: That still doesn't really answer how to remove a target added to a buttn for a UIControlEvent. What would I pass as the parameters to `removeObserver`?

Comment: Typically the observer calls `removeObserver:self name:@"some_notification_name" object:theObservableObject`.

Comment: It's how `@"some_notification_name"` relates to a UIButton's TouchUpInside event which I don't understand. Is it just `@"UIButton_TouchUpInside"?`

Comment: I'm not sure with the correct method for buttons, but for a generic NSNotification it's just a string to identify it. The observable/poster posts it, and the observer is listening for it.

Comment: I've used `NSNotificationCenter` with custom events in the past, but this seems different.